# CPLEX/OPL search phases without variable chooser

Tags: cplex, constraint-programming, ilog, opl

I have an OPL CP model in IBM ILOG CPLEX. It is possible only to set CP search phases with decision variable, variable chooser and value chooser.

Somehow like that :

```
execute {
var f = cp.factory;

var phase1 = f.searchPhase(slot, 
          f.selectSmallest(f.varIndex(slot)), 
          f.selectLargest(f.explicitValueEval(values, valueEval, 0)));

cp.setSearchPhases(phase1);}
```

Is there any option to set search phases with decision variable, value chooser but without variable chooser?

Answer (score 0):

> execute { var f = cp.factory;
>
> var phase1 = f.searchPhase(slot, 
>             f.selectRandomVar(),
>             f.selectLargest(f.explicitValueEval(values, valueEval, 0)));
>
> cp.setSearchPhases(phase1);
>
> }

regards